# Switching a resistor ladder

Tags: signal, switching

Can anyone suggest how i could switch this resistor ladder with the smallest possible footprint.  I was looking up analog switches but not sure if thats the right way to go.[image]

[image]
The circuit tells an ecu what speed to run the engine at, and states the resistor tolerance at 5%.  I am looking to control this circuit with an mcu and would like suggestions of what sort of IC could be used as a switch.  it would have to have a low Ron (6ohm) to keep in spec with resistor tolerance.

Thanks in advance

Comment: if switch is permanently closed, then why do you have switch 6 and the 2200Ω resistor?  .... take them out ..... what does this mean? `The circuit carries 5v`

Comment: post edited....

Comment: what does this mean? `The circuit is 5v` ..... please label the circuit with +V, GND, INPUTS

Comment: post edited....

Comment: Consider MCU outputs that can be TRI-STATED, as well as pull low.

Answer (score 1):

> I am looking to control this circuit with an mcu and would like
>   suggestions of what sort of IC could be used as a switch

In this case your best bet would be to use digital POT, something like [MCP4141](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22059b.pdf) or [AD7376](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD7376.pdf). This one chip alone will replace all the resistors and switches and is extremely easy to control by MCU, with probably the smallest footprint possible.

For non-MCU control there are hundreds of miniature [rotary switches](https://dznh3ojzb2azq.cloudfront.net/products/Rotary/RM/documents/datasheet.pdf) available dirt cheap.

Comment: How have I never heard of a digital pot before, that might have been useful in a project I did recently thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

For many applications, I would say go with the analog switch.  That said, you have some pretty low resistor values, and you need to be absolutely sure that your on resistance of the switch doesn't do anything nasty.

If you can't convince yourself that it's OK, I'd consider SSR's.  You can get them in some pretty small packages.  See http://www.ixysic.com/Products/SSRFormA.htm for one product line.  You can get quads in small packages -- e.g., https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/vni4140k-32-974430.pdf

Answer (score 0):

If your MCU has a D-A converter, you could just use that output, buffered through an op-amp to force the top of the divider string to the appropriate voltage to simulate the divider, given that you have a description of the way the signal is interpreted by the ECU, which will just be employing an A-D to interpret the control input. Most likely it'll have defined transition points that set the accepted voltage range for each of the states, but whether there are guard bands between each valid state or not to dismiss unacceptable variations in the value will depend on the criticality of the operation. On setups I've created for reading keys in this manner I haven't bothered beyond open/short detection, but they weren't for an engine ECU.

Answer (score 0):

Smallest footprint is PWM and a single 120 ohm resistor.

The 220 nF capacitor will smooth out the lumps caused by the PWM to some extent but increasing the capacitor will probably help, from what I understand from the blurb the other end of the wire is a resistor to +5V,a another capacitor to ground, and something that reads the voltage.

You get a time constant of about 50 us so an 8-bit PWM running at say 20Mhz clock speed should be able to get close-enough to the needed voltages to trigger the commands.